# Swift UIColor Extensions best practice

Tags: swift, uicolor

So recently I've been looking at defining some custom colors in a UIColor extension but I've seen various ways of doing this. Is there a best practice about this documented anywhere?

For instance I've seen both of these ways used:

```
   extension UIColor {
     static let myColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
 }

 //called like UIColor.myColor
```

or

```
 extension UIColor {
   static var myColor: UIColor {

    return UIColor(red:1, green:1, blue:1, alpha:1.0)
}
 }
  //called like UIColor.myColor
```

Is there a non-opinion based best practice here? Or is it just down to personal preference?  (I am aware that the color in the example isn't actually custom :D )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the benefit of the second approach is that every caller receives a new instance just for them. They can each mutate their copy and not effect the others.

With the first technique, one caller can get a reference to the shared `UIColor` object, and modify it so that it effects all other callers, globally. However, since `UIColor` isn't mutable, this isn't a concern.

In the case with an immutable object like UI colour, it's better to go with the first option, as it'll save memory (all callers get a reference to a single shared object, rather than copies).